# What could cause vkCreateDevice() to fail without giving a reason for failure?

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm learning vulkan with the vulkan cookbook, and I now find myself at an impasse:

If I try to pass extensions, namely, `VK_KHR_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME` and `VK_KHR_WIN32_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME` in the list of extensions in the `VkDeviceCreateInfo` structure that I send to `vkCreateDevice`, the function fails without any error (It doeesn't return `VK_SUCCESS`)

I've checked, and I know that my graphics card supports all the extensions that I'm trying to pass. I tried reading the output from validation layers, but they don't seem to catch the reason for failure (I enabled the `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_api_dump` and standard validation layers).

My function to create a logical device looks like this-

```
bool create_logical_device(VkPhysicalDevice &physDev, VkDevice &device,
                           std::vector<char const *> &desExts,
                           std::vector<queueInfo> &qInfos,
                           VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures &physDevFtrs) 
{
  std::vector<VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo> qCreateInfo;
  std::vector<VkExtensionProperties> physDevExtProps;

  if (!get_avl_phys_dev_exts(physDev, physDevExtProps))
    return false;

  for (auto &ext : desExts) 
  {
    if (!is_ext_available(physDevExtProps, ext))
      return false;
  }

  for (auto &i : qInfos) 
  {
    qCreateInfo.push_back(
        {VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_QUEUE_CREATE_INFO, 
            nullptr, 
            0, 
            i.FamilyIndex,
            (uint32_t)i.Priorities.size(),
            i.Priorities.size() > 0 ? i.Priorities.data() : nullptr
        });
  }

  VkDeviceCreateInfo devCreateInfo = 
  {
      VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO,
      nullptr,
      0,
      (uint32_t)qCreateInfo.size(),
      qCreateInfo.size() > 0 ? qCreateInfo.data() : nullptr,
      0,
      nullptr,
      (uint32_t)desExts.size(),
      desExts.size() > 0 ? desExts.data() : nullptr,
      &physDevFtrs

  };



#ifdef ENABLE_VALIDATION
  devCreateInfo.enabledLayerCount = (uint32_t)valLayers.size();
  devCreateInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = valLayers.data();
#endif

  if (vkCreateDevice(physDev, &devCreateInfo, nullptr, &device) != VK_SUCCESS) 
  {
    std::cout << "Could not create logical device!" << std::endl;
    return false;
  }

  std::cout << "Succesfully created logical device" << std::endl;

  return true;
}
```

`valLayers` is a constant vector in the global scope.

This failure occurs on both windows and linux, so it can only be something on my side. Running the code through the debugger didn't reveal anything to me. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: If it doesn't return VK_SUCCESS what does it return instead?

Comment: Are You sure You are providing valid extension names? VK_KHR_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME is an instance extension, so it shouldn't be provided during device creation.

Comment: I think that must be what is happenning.... I'll check.

Comment: @Ekzuzy, That fixed the problem, Thank you. Turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are You sure You are providing valid extension names? VK_KHR_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME is an instance extension, so it shouldn't be provided during device creation.

And thanks for using/reading/learning from the *Vulkan Cookbook* ;-).